# singular or plural for index entries

Tags: style, technical-writing, indexing

I am in the final stages of writing a book and currently I am preparing the index.  Are there any rules whether index entries should be listed in singular or plural?
Currently I have

```
Markov chains, 20, 30-40, 50
    with discrete state space, 33
    with continuous state space, 38
```

Should I change this to "Markov chain"?

Comment: Why not just: _Markov chain(s): 20, 30..._ [or alternatively _Markov chain (s): 20, 30..._ - note the space before the (s)]

Comment: @JedOliver: This sounds all good, but a bit ad-hoc.  My question is mostly about whether there are commonly accepted rules.  There seem to be style guides for everything, but I couldn't find one for indices ...

Comment: In that case I may need more information. _Which_ manual of style are you using? Chicago? MLA? CSE? Turabian? I know CMoS has an extensive set of guidelines for proper and preferred formatting for indexes. Whether or not they cover plurals, I don't know. Of course, that will only help you in Chicago style - but it _is_ a comprehensive style guide for indexes (the plural of the word meaning alphabetical list, and not the word indicative of numerical expressions, which is still indices).

Comment: I am not bound by a specific style guide.  Thus, if the  answer depends on the style guido chosen I can equally well make up my own.  The book went to the publisher yesterday, so it's too late now anyway ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it depends on how the item is discussed in the body of the book.

If a Markov chain is something referred to as a single entity, then index it as a single item. If you discuss several of them at once, or generalize (like saying "black holes have thus-and-such properties"), I'd use the plural.

Comment: This is what I do.  In the doc I'm currently working on, I talk about the such-and-such server (singular) and index it in the singular, but I talk about the things returned from that server in the plural and index them that way.

Comment: This seems to make sense, but I wonder whether there are generally accepted rules about such matters or whether everybody makes up his/her own rules.

Comment: I agree that being able to bring a source would be better, and I don't have one to hand.  I wonder which style guides cover indexing and not just "body copy"?

Comment: This being the only answer, it is clearly the best!  It is hereby accepted :)